# android facebook integration get email

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated facebook login into my app according to the tutorial, but I cant find any good info on how to retrieve the user's email address.  The email is really the only thing I need.  I am able to get other basic info.  My activity extends FaceBookActivity.  When the user clicks to log in to my app, I call:

```
this.openSession();
```

Then I have:

```
@Override
    protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception) 
    {
          // user has either logged in or not ...
          if (state.isOpened()) 
          {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request request = Request.newMeRequest(
                  this.getSession(),
                  new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                  {
                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                        {
                          if (user != null) 
                          {  
                            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            Log.d("user fname",user.getFirstName());
                            Log.d("user lname",user.getLastName());
                            Log.d("user username",user.getUsername());
                            Log.d("user email",(String)user.getProperty("email"));

                      }
                    }
              }
            );

                Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
          }
    }
```

GraphUser does not expose the email.  Any ideas?

I have set the 'email' permission in my facebook dev panel.

Comment: Are you requesting the 'email' permission in your authentication code?

Comment: i dont have authentication code.  all the code is what you see above, which works for the basic info.

Comment: Yes, and the email address is not part of the basic info - you need the `email` permission to be granted by the user

Comment: But I set the email permission in the facebook dev panel.

Comment: that only applies to Authenticated Referrals or when people click through to your web app from the App Center - for mobile apps, apps people access directly, websites where people will arrive there other than via Facebook.com's app center or apps not using authenticated referrals, you need to prompt the user for the appropriate permissions

Answer (score 6):

For the new Facebook sdk 3.0

```
String email = (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email");
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured this out.  The GraphUser object will contain the email address but I found a tutorial that approaches login completely different from the basic tutorial.

Here is the basic tutorial:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

And here is the tutorial you must implement in addition to the basic tutorial to get this to work:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#step3

What you have to do is implement the 1st login sample, then go and change it up to the 2nd sample, then use parts of the first sample in your final product.  If you carefully go through each tutorial starting with the first one I posted, you will get this to work and learn how to capture any data you want from the user by implementing additional permission requests.

Hope this helps someone else.  All of the questions I searched on 'SO' refer to older API's with outdated methods.

Answer (score 0):

For more permissions You can change .openSession() function to .openSessionForRead(String appId, List < String > Permissions) if You have app_id on strings.xml run .openSessionForRead(null, List Permissions)